# Any hosting that support Matisse database?

Tags: database, nosql

I am looking for a hosting that support Matisse database. I've been googling for a while and I didn't find anything. Someone can help me?

Anyway, my goal is to use a DBOO, so if you others that works fine, feel free to recommend me other options.

Thanks!

Comment: You could always rent a whole server (physical or virtual). You can then install any software you want on it.

Answer (score 0):

If they provide a distributable executable which i could not find on their site, you could install it on ec2 or azure compute.

you could also try [Amisa Server as a service](http://www.amisalabs.com/)

Comment: Thanks... will investigate on it... =)